# numpy get indexes of connected array values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, split

I have a 1d numpy array that looks like this:

```py
a = np.array([1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1])
```

Is there a way to get the indexes of start and end of each cluster of values. So basically I would get this:

```py
[
    # clusters with value 1 (cluster with values 0 aren't needed)
    [
        # start and end of each cluster
        [0, 2],
        [8, 11],
        [13, 14],
    ],
]
```

I'm not very skilled with numpy. I know there are lots of cool functions, but I have no idea which ones to use. Also googling this problem didn't give me anything since people usually have pretty specific problems that are different than mine. I know that for example `np.split` won't be enough here.

Please help me if you can, I can provide you with more examples or details if needed. I'll try to respond as quickly as possible. Thank you for you time.

Comment: Do you have to use *numpy* here?  Or python is fine>?

Comment: Yes, I'm processing a lot of data.